# Spring Data Elasticsearch dynamic properties

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my Elasticsearch I have the following document:

```
  {
    "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
    "_type" : "Decision",
    "_id" : "1620",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name.value" : "Default name",
      "name_en.value" : "Name [EN]",
      "name_fr.value" : "Name [FR]",
      "name_it.value" : "Name [IT]",
      "createDate" : 1511779747939
    }
  }
```

Currently, I don't know exact name.* properties. They can vary from one document to another. For example, one document can have only "name_en.value" but another one - "name_fr.value" and "name_es.value"

Right now I don't know how to handle these properties in Spring Data Elasticsearch model. I have the following class:

```
@Document(indexName = ESDecision.INDEX_NAME, type = ESDecision.TYPE)
public class ESDecision {

    public static final String INDEX_NAME = "neo4j-index-node";
    public static final String TYPE = "Decision";

    @Id
    private String esId;


...

}
```

Unfortunately,  I don't know the exact properties in order to statically add them into this model.

How to add support for these dynamic properties to this class? Is it for example possible to use `Map<String, String> nameMap` property in order to have all of these properties as keys in this map and place appropriate values under these keys?